# How to make bootstrap alert same size as input in a form-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">

    <form id="register-form" action="/register" method="POST">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">This username is taken</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
```

I would like for a `<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">This username is taken</div>` to appear beside (on the right side) the  for username;the alert being the height and width.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by beside? left or right?

Comment: Go for this  `<div class="form-group row">
          <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control col" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
          <div class="alert alert-danger col py-1 my-auto" role="alert">This username is taken</div>
        </div>`

Comment: @mahan To the right

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure you layout.

- Use  `.container-xl`.
- Wrap the whole content on the form in a column and offset the column so that its content is centered when the alert is not visible.
- Use a seperate row with two columns for each of the inputs.
- Remove the padding of the alrert and give it 100 height.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-xl">
  <form class="row justify-content-center" id="register-form" action="/register" method="POST">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 offset-lg-4">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control h-100" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="alert alert-danger py-0 h-100  d-flex align-items-center" role="alert">This username is taken</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <input class="form-control" name="confirm-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 pl-md-0">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

---